# transform property not working in IE on <use> in svg image when svg image importing from external html file

Tags: svg

index.html

```html
<div class="button-icon">
  <svg width="950px" height="605px" viewBox="0 0 950 605" >
  <use xlink:href="assets/svgs/front-view-1-g2.svg#front-view-1-g2"  />
  </svg>
</div>
```

front-view-1-g2.svg

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
    <defs>
        <g id="dark-rectangle" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" >
            <text id="2" font-family="AvenirPrimaryHMHMath" font-size="10" width="12" height="12"  font-weight="normal" fill="#000000">
                <tspan x="83" y="15">31</tspan>
            </text>
            <rect id="path-1" transform="translate(83.000000, 17.000000)" x="0" y="0" width="12" height="12"  fill="#9b9b9b" ></rect>
        </g>
        
    </defs>
    <g id="iPad" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="front-view-1-g2">
                <use  xlink:href="#dark-rectangle"></use>
                <use transform="translate(110.000000, 0.000000)" xlink:href="#dark-rectangle"></use>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

i have only one group but needed to call it 2 times and change the position of second group and that is why i used transform to second  use tag but its not working in IE browser.

if i put use tag in html file then also transform not working in IE.
it works properly in Chrome and Mozilla.

Note : use tag not working when mentioned in .svg file and transform not working when use mentioned in .html file.

Comment: Which version of IE? The second one works correctly for me in IE11.

Comment: I too using IE11. but when i do like this in .html file                                                <div class="button-icon">
  <svg width="950px" height="605px" viewBox="0 0 950 605" >
 <use  xlink:href="assets/svgs/front-view-1-g2.svg#dark-rectangle"</use>
 <use transform="translate(110.000000, 0.000000)" xlink:href="assets/svgs/front-view-1-g2.svg#dark-rectangle"></use>
  </svg>
</div>     then transform not working in IE11. second called group placing on first one in IE.   Please help

Comment: Do you mean that the transform doesn't work if your `<use>` element links to an external file?  But it works if the `<use>` links to something internal?

Comment: yes, transform not works when  <use> element links from external file because <use> not renders in IE and that is why transform not applies to it but it gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey I found the answer for this.

Transform will work on use tag in IE as IE will not render tag, it directly renders particular group's child elements from .svg file.

In above case of mine, I need to create another rectangle group assign transform to it and use that group.